# Running php script in difference directories

Tags: php

I test this /usr/bin/php /path/index.php to run a php script without being in script directory and it works, but I have a problem. When I run it in different directories, script outputs files will appear in same directories and not in path/index.php. How can I solve it?

Comment: Please elaborate. When you run `any-command /path/to/file` the forward slash defines the path as being absolute and thus _can_ be run from anywhere. As to where it outputs, that's a problem with the script itself, please post a small subset of that script that outputs something so that we can help troubleshoot it.

Comment: Define an absolute output path. You can use `__DIR__` to get the file path of the script it's written in. Something like: `$outputPath = __DIR__ . '/somefile.txt';`. You can read more about paths in PHP here: https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths#console